# Could the United States' actions in Hawaii be classified as genocide?

Tags: united-states, genocide

The native Hawaiian are very different then the rest of America.

The overthrow of the Hawaiian Kingdom began on January 17, 1893, with a coup d'état against Queen Lili'uokalani on the island of Oahu by subjects of the Hawaiian Kingdom, United States citizens, and foreign residents residing in Honolulu. A majority of the insurgents were foreigners.

Comment: Welcome to Politics SE!  This site seeks to provide factual, impartial answers to questions about politics, procedure and personalities.  Questions asking us to express an opinion on what amounts to genocide is off-topic on this site.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help/on-topic] to learn what kinds of questions are on-topic here, and if you can [edit] your question to make it on-topic, you should take a moment to do so.

Comment: The equivalent question about the Chinese government and the Uyghur population seems to be doing fine.

Comment: @HawaiianKingdom - I doubt you would too many people who would argue that merely overthrowing a foreign government, with or without the support of local discontents, counts as genocide. For instance, that's why you will sometimes find people accusing George W. Bush of war crimes for the invasion of Iraq and overthrow of Saddam Hussein, but rarely genocide.  Perhaps some actions that the US government took previously or subsequently, but not the mere fact of the conquest.

Comment: Now, with a broader focus, some of the massacres and so forth against Native Americans in the continental US clearly rose to the level of genocide.

Comment: It would seem difficult to describe the US takeover as "genocide", considering that - per the Wikipedia article - the US forces never fired a shot: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overthrow_of_the_Hawaiian_Kingdom#United_States_involvement

Comment: @Fattie: It's not an absolutely identical question.  At the very least, the answers would be considerably different, based on historical facts.  Simply as a question, it would be much better suited to the History site.  It's certainly not current politics.

Comment: I'm voting to close as "promoting a cause". There are a number of problems with this question. First, it seems to be mirroring the question about the Uyghur population. You seem to be "making a point". Next, It doesn't show any research. (You don't reference the definition of genocide in the other question)  Thirdly it is historical, not political.  Is there any reasonable claim of an ongoing genocide in Hawaii? The USA certainly committed multiple genocides against various Native American peoples, the 1893 coup is hardly the best example of genocide committed by the USA.

Comment: Come on. I disagree with the idea that it was likely a genocide, but it is clearly pertinent to modern political issues in Hawai'i.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on History.

Comment: I don't have the time or inclination to search for it, but if anyone can find a modern politician, even from a marginal party, calling it genocide (should not be too hard) or something similar, perhaps that would pacify the naysayers.

Comment: Whether it rises to the level of "genocide" is up to interpretations of each individual but still an interesting question. Anything that sheds light on the darkness of the west isn't welcomed here :)

Comment: @HawaiianKingdom: your question appears to conflate coup d'état and [genocide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genocide) which are two very different things. Is there any evidence that native Hawaiians were killed or harmed in a systematic way as a group?